# My phone loses connection after sending 150-200 sms

Tags: sms, connection-issues

I'm sms spamming to my business number (because of a campaign from my provider). But after sending 150-200 sms from my personal number to any number my phone loses connection. I called the service provider of my personal phone that I use to send sms. They said it shouldn't happen. I'm using an application for sms spamming and it is sending 1 sms per second. Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge 32GB Android 7.0 rooted.

Comment: I don't think that automated sending of SMS is covered by your cell phone plan. Most likely they throttle the incoming SMS messages and your phone baseband is crashing because of blocking messages. Mass SMS messages are usually sent via backend systems directly via Internet, not over the air from a cell phone.

Comment: Which phone loses connection – the sender or the receiver? There's a limit to how many SMS you can send per hour (or was it per half-hour, I don't remember). That limit can be configured. Ah, there it is: [Change the SMS Limit on Android so you can Send More Messages](https://www.xda-developers.com/change-sms-limit-android/)

Comment: @Robert I talked with my provider and they said it shouldn't happening because they have no limit about sending sms as they said.

Comment: @Izzy sender phone loses connection. It say not registered on network after sending 150-200 sms. When I restart the phone I'm able to send sms again. And I did what it says on the guide but it's still the same.

Comment: @BaranGündüzYILDIRIM It does not matter if or if not your provider has a limit. If the setting that Izzy linked to has no effect then your phone baseband seem to crash because of bulk sending SMS. Therefore you have two choices: reduce the number of sent SMS per minute or use different phone (or try to install a different ROM).

Comment: i don't think that your provider is aware of the specific hardware of cell towers around your location. even if your contract has no restrictictions, the company who owns that cell towers may restrict spamming. but thats guesswork

Comment: @alecxs How can I reduce the number of sent SMS per minute? Btw I tried to use different phones with my sim card. They were all the same. I tried on 3 different model of samsung phones.